# Bound Textbox to a currency, how to get the double?

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, masking

I have a textbox bound to a currency data field. So it adds '$' to the start of the text or ($xx.xx) if it's negative. How do I get just the plain double (xx.xx) from the textbox instead of everything ($xx.xx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you set the proper NumberStyles flags when calling double.Parse.

Obviously, you'd use the example below but replace the literal string with a reference to the text in the TextBox.

```
double d = double.Parse ("$10.10", NumberStyles.Currency);
```

Comment: Great! Thank you. I understand that the '|' is a bitwise OR, but how does it allow me to pass all of those options? I may make a separate question about this.

Comment: That big long line can actually be replaced with:
Double.Parse("$10.10", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency);
And it will handle all of them, including Thousand separators (which you didn't include)